# Question about special relativity in Carroll lecture note

Tags: special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

In the lecture of General relativity by [Carroll](https://preposterousuniverse.com/wp-content/uploads/grnotes-one.pdf), page 7 is written that:

Notice the distinction between this situation and that in the
Newtonian world; here,

> **it is impossible to say (in a coordinate-independent way) whether a point that is spacelike separated from $p$ is in the future of
>   $p$, the past of $p$, or“at the same time”.**

I can not truly understand this sentence, could someone help me out? Why is it impossible?

Comment: the points are "spacelike separated" meaning it takes longer for a signal to be communicated than it takes light to travel, thus they are acausally connected. The light cone depicts this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Light_cone

Comment: @N.Steinle, thanks, I know this. I just want the meaning of the 2 above sentences.

Comment: You should be more specific about how the statement confuses you.

Comment: If 2 events (points in spacetime) p & q are spacelike separated then in some frames p occurs before q, in some frames p & q are simultaneous, and in other frames q occurs before p. There is no absolute ordering in time of p & q.

Comment: @PM2Ring, what does it mean exactly: p & q are spacelike separated? one of them is in the origin and one outside of lightcone of the first one, or what? I can not imagine the position of these two point to understand this.

Comment: @N.Steinle, what is exactly, a point is spacelike from p, means?

Comment: Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Spacetime_interval Understanding the spacetime interval, and the difference between timelike, lightlike, and spacelike intervals is fundamental to relativity.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#/media/File:Relativity_of_Simultaneity_Animation.gif which is Fig. 2-6 on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Relativity_of_simultaneity

Answer (score 1):

> what is exactly, a point is spacelike from p, means?

On the same page, Carroll gives this definition:

> Light cones are naturally divided into future and past; the set of all points inside the future and past light cones of a point p are called timelike separated from p, while those outside the light cones are spacelike separated and those on the cones are lightlike or null separated from p

Comment: Thanks! maybe it was the terminology misunderstanding! Then it means first we fix $p$ than with respect to the future of $p$ we take another point that is outside of light cone with the origin $p$. Now, if the second point is outside the lightcone and in the upper plane ($z>0$) then it should be in the non-accessible future of $p$ and so on..., is not so?